# Clear echo and post in JS

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with a php calculator application. I wanted to make something like this:

When the results appear and I hit the reset button,  the reset function should not apply just to HTML, but to the result echo, too.

I don't want the page to be refreshed.

Here is some code:

```
<form method="POST">

<input type="number" name="fn"></input>
<select name="operation">
<option value="p">+</option>
<option value="mi">-</option>
<option value="mu">*</option>
<option value="d">/</option>
</select>
<input type="number" name="sn"></input> <br/>
<input type="submit" name="sub"></input>
<input type="reset" name="restart"></input>

</form>

<?php 
if (isset($_REQUEST['sub'])) {


if($_REQUEST["operation"] == "p") {
$fn = $_REQUEST["fn"];
$sn = $_REQUEST["sn"];

$res = $fn + $sn;

ob_start();
$restring = "The result of " . $fn . " + " . $sn . " is: " . "<b>" . $res . "</b>";
echo $restring;

if(isset($_REQUEST["restart"])) {
global $restring;
ob_end_clear();
}
}



if($_REQUEST["operation"] == "mi") {
$fn = $_REQUEST["fn"];
$sn = $_REQUEST["sn"];

$res = $fn - $sn;

echo "The result of " . $fn . " - " . $sn . " is: " . "<b>" . $res . "</b>";

}



if($_REQUEST["operation"] == "mu") {
$fn = $_REQUEST["fn"];
$sn = $_REQUEST["sn"];

$res = $fn * $sn;

echo "The result of " . $fn . " * " . $sn . " is: " . "<b>" . $res . "</b>";

}




if($_REQUEST["operation"] == "d") {
$fn = $_REQUEST["fn"];
$sn = $_REQUEST["sn"];

$res = $fn / $sn;

echo "The result of " . $fn . " / " . $sn . " is: " . "<b>" . $res . "</b>";

}

}
?>
```

Comment: I tryied to define a result global variable and use ob_end_clear, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use JavaScript to clear the output without refreshing the page.

First, you need to give your reset button an id so you can attach onclick event to it:

```
<input type="reset" name="restart" id="reset"></input>
```

Later, you attach the onclick event:

```
var reset = document.getElementById("reset");
reset.onclick = function() {
    var output = document.getElementById("output");
    document.body.removeChild(output);
}
```

Since you need to clear the output, the output element needs to be accessible. That's why you can't just echo a string:

<strike>`$restring = "The result of " . $fn . " + " . $sn . " is: " . "<b>" . $res . "</b>";`</strike>

Make it a paragraph, for example, and since you'll clear/reset it, you should also give it an id to access it.

```
$restring = "<p id=\"output\">The result of $fn + $sn is: <b>$res</b></p>";
```

Since the output paragraph will be directly inside the body element

```
document.body.removeChild(output);
```

line will remove it from the page.

Here's your working code:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="number" name="fn"></input>
    <select name="operation">
        <option value="p">+</option>
        <option value="mi">-</option>
        <option value="mu">*</option>
        <option value="d">/</option>
    </select>
    <input type="number" name="sn"></input> <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="sub"></input>
    <input type="reset" name="restart" id="reset"></input>
</form>

<script>
    var reset = document.getElementById("reset");
    reset.onclick = function() {
        var output = document.getElementById("output");
        document.body.removeChild(output);
    }
</script>

<?php
    if (isset($_REQUEST['sub'])) {

        if($_REQUEST["operation"] == "p") {
            $fn = $_REQUEST["fn"];
            $sn = $_REQUEST["sn"];

            $res = $fn + $sn;

            $restring = "<p id=\"output\">The result of $fn + $sn is: <b>$res</b></p>";

            echo $restring;
        }

        if($_REQUEST["operation"] == "mi") {
            $fn = $_REQUEST["fn"];
            $sn = $_REQUEST["sn"];

            $res = $fn - $sn;

            $restring = "<p id=\"output\">The result of $fn - $sn is: <b>$res</b></p>";

            echo $restring;
        }

        if($_REQUEST["operation"] == "mu") {
            $fn = $_REQUEST["fn"];
            $sn = $_REQUEST["sn"];

            $res = $fn * $sn;

            $restring = "<p id=\"output\">The result of $fn * $sn is: <b>$res</b></p>";

            echo $restring;
        }

        if($_REQUEST["operation"] == "d") {
            $fn = $_REQUEST["fn"];
            $sn = $_REQUEST["sn"];

            $res = $fn / $sn;

            $restring = "<p id=\"output\">The result of $fn / $sn is: <b>$res</b></p>";

            echo $restring;
        }
    }
?>
```

---

Also here's something to study:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="number" name="firstNumber"></input>
    <select name="operation">
        <option value="plus">+</option>
        <option value="minus">-</option>
        <option value="multiply">*</option>
        <option value="divide">/</option>
    </select>
    <input type="number" name="secondNumber"></input> <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"></input>
    <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset"></input>
</form>

<script>
    var reset = document.getElementById("reset");
    reset.onclick = function() {
        var output = document.getElementById("output");
        document.body.removeChild(output);
    }
</script>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $firstNumber    = $_POST["firstNumber"];
        $secondNumber   = $_POST["secondNumber"];

        function output($operation, $result) {
            global $firstNumber, $secondNumber;
            echo "<p id=\"output\">The result of $firstNumber $operation $secondNumber is: <b>$result</b></p>";
        }

        switch ($_POST["operation"]) {
            case "plus":
                $result = $firstNumber + $secondNumber;
                output("+", $result);
                break;
            case "minus":
                $result = $firstNumber - $secondNumber;
                output("-", $result);
                break;
            case "multiply":
                $result = $firstNumber * $secondNumber;
                output("*", $result);
                break;
            case "divide":
                $result = $firstNumber / $secondNumber;
                output("/", $result);
                break;
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add you echo result on some container like div 
For eg.

```
<div Id="output">the result is 10</div>.
```

Nd then hide this element when reset button is clicked using JavaScript

Your JavaScript function would be like this

```
function resetEcho()
{
document.getElementById("output").style.display="none";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using only php You need to refresh the page for resetting the echo. You can  use ajax for achieving this functionality (for getting data without page refresh) or use  Jquery library Load Method. 
[Jquery load documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

See an example below (This will reload the div for you).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
       $('#reset').click(function(){
        
           $("#divId").load(location.href + "#calculator_holder>*", "");
        
         });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="calculator_holder">
    <form method="POST">
    <input type="number" name="fn"></input>
    <select name="operation">
    <option value="p">+</option>
    <option value="mi">-</option>
    <option value="mu">*</option>
    <option value="d">/</option>
    </select>
    <input type="number" name="sn"></input> <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="sub"></input>
    <input type="reset" name="restart" id="reset"></input>
    
    </form>
    </div>
```